# Hosting Laravel 4.2 project on share hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hosting

I have successfully uploaded my Laravel 4.2 project on share hosting with the contents of other folders uploaded directly in root directory, then the content of public folder uploaded in `public_html`.

But when I access the URL I get this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php on line 426
```

Has anyone experience this before?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you got an unsupported version of PHP.

Laravel 4.2 uses the short array syntax introduced in PHP 5.4.